# How to display custom view for a menu for tvOS with Swift?

Tags: swift, tvos

[Application on tvOS displaying menu + details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmi7n.jpg)

On the above image, that is an application on tvOS (Youtube) displaying a menu and its details (the background is not important). The menu is the red rectangle and the details is the white rectangle.
I know that the red rectangle uses UITabBarController and 2 UITabBarItems (Info and Audio). When you implement a basic UITabBarController, you specify the title for every BarItem. In this app, when "Info" is focused, it displays the white rectangle below.

**How can you implement in Swift the white rectangle ?**

And when "Audio" is focused, it displays another white rectangle with different contents.

For example, when "Info" is focused and you slide down with your remote, it will focus the object inside the white rectangle and keeps displaying the menu.

**Do you have to implement manually by yourself the white rectangle ?** (Like be aware what menu item was focused and keep it displays) 
**Or is there something in UITabBarController or UITabItem or something else that manage it for you ?** Like you provide your custom UIView when a menu item is selected and the component handle it for you ?